# Sharing to social pages with django

Tags: django, facebook, integration, social-networking, google-buzz

In my django application I have different content across the site. Now I would like to add "Share this to... (Facebook,Twitter,Buzz)" link on each page. But instead of redirecting to a social app page I would like to open popup with (if needed) logging/adding possibility. How to get started ? What steps/operations I need to perform and what ready made applications can I use ? I have already created a twitter app and facebook app and have all the keys.

I mean something like links here http://mashable.com/awards/ (left-side).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sharethis: http://sharethis.com/ works well in every instance I've used it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want only specific 'share buttons' or with default style justy type " social_name 'share button' " and you will get the js to include on your site (here are the 3 you mentioned in post):

http://www.facebook.com/share/
http://twitter.com/goodies/tweetbutton
http://www.google.com/buzz/api/admin/configPostWidget

Comment: Can you expand on this answer, it is not entirely complete.

Comment: this is the new google +1 button http://www.google.com/intl/fr/webmasters/+1/button/index.html?utm_source=b2cp1&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=p1

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the app written to behave like mashable, one approach is to put the login dialog (if it's needed) in a jQuery dialog.  http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/